# How to pass a variable from current window to another window

Tags: javascript, jquery

First Page

```
<button onclick="refereceid_Transfer()">Try it</button>

<script>


function refereceid_Transfer() {
alert('test');
var referenceid = "jggd154278";
referenceid = btoa(referenceid);
//sessionStorage.setItem("sent", referenceid); 
 window.open("second.jsp", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
}

</script>
```

Second Page

```
<p id="s1"></p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // var a = sessionStorage.getItem("sent",id);
alert(a);
});  
</script>
```

I need to pass my reference id from one window to another window. I tried use session storage and local storage to pass variable and i have failed in both condition. is there new suggestion that i can pass my reference id to new window.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for this.

Add item which you want to pass on another page:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

On another page you can access through:

```
localStorage.getItem("key");
```

You can store object data as well in **localStorage**. Note that clear **localStorage** if you're storing some sensitive information.

And simpler option is to use query parameter, but I think you're not okay with it.

Or you can use **sessionStorage**:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("key", data);
window.open("page_url","_blank");
```

on another page use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    var data = sessionStorage.getItem("key");
    console.dir(data);
});
```

**Note**: *The sessionStorage object is equal to the localStorage object, except that it stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the specific browser tab.*

Comment: Thanks so in case if wanted put on sever side, i need to session storage is it ? because i working on localhost later i will hosted into my website that why i posted this question.

Comment: Okay, post me if any issue. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with local storage or you can pass it in query parameters and read the query parameters at 2nd page.
If you are doing server side rendering you can also use session storage.

Comment: even though its java script its all going to be under a server side code so local storage wont be an effect is it or it can cause me problem.

Comment: My last solution will be parameter but i am trying to do without parameters since i am passing an ID

Comment: I have updated my answer, as you said you are doing server side rendering, you can also use session storage.